# How to setup virtual hosts in XAMPP at any directory on ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php, xampp

How to setup virtual hosts in XAMPP at any directory on Ubuntu >=18.04.

How to setup and run different websites at a time. Those website directories are located at different paths in my computer

Answer (score 0):

> *I am assuming the installation path of xampp is at `/opt/lampp/`*

- Open `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` with text editor.
- Search for `ServerName localhost` in the file. right below the line you will
  find following lines.

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

- add following code right below to the aforementioned lines

```
<Directory /path/to/your/folder>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

> remember */path/to/your/folder* means all *folders* in this directory will be allowed by apache to use

- **Open** `opt/lamp/etc/extra/http-vhosts.conf` in editor and add a website you need using following as a example.

```
<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:PORT>
  DocumentRoot "PATH/TO/WEBISTE/ROOT"
  ServerName WEBSITE-HOST-NAME
  <Directory "PATH/TO/WEBISTE/ROOT">
      Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```